# Trying to store many rectangles without duplicate areas efficiently in ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, shapes

I'd like to store several rectangles in one variable in ruby. It's in order to add rectangles in which the screen must be refreshed. I tried it with a class Rectangle with top, left, height and with, and stored rectangle variables in an array. But it's much too slow when iterating over it and calculating with it.

When adding a new rectangle, there shouldn't be any duplicates on the screen to refresh, and it shouldn't take much time to calculate in order to remove duplicates (no time in the best case).

Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker and many thanks for your ideas!

require 'Rectangles'

class Rectangle

```
attr_accessor :top,:left,:height,:width

def initialize(options={})
    @top=options[:top]
    @left=options[:left]
    @height=options[:height]
    @width=options[:width]
end

def bottom
    @top+@height-1
end

def right
    @left+@width-1
end

def coveredBy?(rectangle)
    return false if @top<rectangle.top
    return false if @left<rectangle.left
    return false if bottom>rectangle.bottom
    return false if right>rectangle.right
    return true
end

def intersection!(rectangle)
    if @top<rectangle.top
        @top=rectangle.top
    end
    if @left<rectangle.left
        @left=rectangle.left
    end
    if bottom>(t=rectangle.bottom)
        @height=rectangle.bottom+1-@top
    end
    if right>(t=rectangle.right)
        @width=rectangle.right+1-@left
    end
end

def &(rectangle)
    if @top>=rectangle.top
        top=@top
    else
        top=rectangle.top
    end
    if @left>=rectangle.left
        left=@left
    else
        left=rectangle.left
    end
    if bottom<=rectangle.bottom
        height=bottom+1-top
    else
        height=rectangle.bottom+1-top
    end
    return nil if height<=0
    if right<=rectangle.right
        width=right+1-left
    else
        width=rectangle.right+1-left
    end
    return nil if width<=0
    return Rectangle.new(
        :top=>top,
        :left=>left,
        :height=>height,
        :width=>width
    )
end

def -(rectArg)
    return [] if empty?
    return [self] if bottom<rectArg.top
    return [self] if @top>rectArg.bottom
    return [self] if right<rectArg.left
    return [self] if @left>rectArg.right

    ret=[]
    line=@top
    if @top<rectArg.top
        ret[ret.count]=Rectangle.new(
            :top=>line,
            :left=>@left,
            :height=>[rectArg.top-@top,@height].min,
            :width=>@width
        )
        line=ret.first.bottom+1
    end
    if @left<rectArg.left
        ret[ret.count]=Rectangle.new(
            :top=>line,
            :left=>@left,
            :height=>[rectArg.bottom+1-line,bottom+1-line].min,
            :width=>[rectArg.left-@left,@width].min
        )
    end
    if right>rectArg.right
        ret[ret.count]=Rectangle.new(
            :top=>line,
            :left=>rectArg.right+1,
            :height=>[rectArg.bottom+1-line,bottom+1-line].min,
            :width=>[right-rectArg.right,@width].min
        )
    end
    if bottom>rectArg.bottom
        ret[ret.count]=Rectangle.new(
            :top=>rectArg.bottom+1,
            :left=>@left,
            :height=>[bottom-rectArg.bottom,@height].min,
            :width=>@width
        )
    end
    ret
 end

# Mit return true geht es deutlich schneller als mit ||.
def outside?(rectangle)
    return true if empty?
    return true if rectangle.empty?
    return true if bottom<rectangle.top
    return true if @top>rectangle.bottom
    return true if right<rectangle.left
    return true if @left>rectangle.right
    return false
 end


 # nebeneinander oder Überschneidung
public def touching?(rectangle)
    horizontalRange=((rectangle.left-1..(rectangle.left+rectangle.width)))
    verticalRange=((rectangle.top-1..(rectangle.top+rectangle.height)))
    horizontalRange.any?{|column|
        column==@left||column==@left+@width
    } &&
    verticalRange.any?{|line|
        line==@top||line==@top+@height
    }
 end

def ==(rectangle)
    #rectangle.kind_of?(self.class) &&
    @top==rectangle.top &&
    @height==rectangle.height &&
    @left==rectangle.left &&
    @width==rectangle.width
end

def !=(rectangle)
    !(self==rectangle)
end

def empty?
    return true if top.nil?
    return true if left.nil?
    return true if height.nil?
    return true if height<=0
    return true if width.nil?
    return true if width<=0
    # @empty=@height<=0 || @width<=0 if @empty.nil?
    # @empty
end

public def area
    # @area||=@height*@width
    # @area
    @height*@width
end

# nur wenn sie passgenau nebeneinander liegen
# (Überschneidungen darf es nicht geben)
public def mergeHorizontally(rectangle)
    return nil if @top!=rectangle.top
    return nil if @height!=rectangle.height
    if @left+@width==rectangle.left
        return Rectangle.new(
            :top=>@top,
            :left=>@left,
            :height=>@height,
            :width=>@width+rectangle.width
        )
    elsif rectangle.left+rectangle.width==@left
        return Rectangle.new(
            :top=>rectangle.top,
            :left=>rectangle.left,
            :height=>rectangle.height,
            :width=>rectangle.width+@width
        )
    else
        return nil
    end
end

# nur wenn sie passgenau nebeneinander liegen
# (Überschneidungen darf es nicht geben)
public def mergeVertically(rectangle)
    return nil if @left!=rectangle.left
    return nil if @width!=rectangle.width
    if @top+@height==rectangle.top
        # return nil
        return Rectangle.new(
            :top=>@top,
            :left=>@left,
            :height=>@height+rectangle.height,
            :width=>@width
        )
    elsif rectangle.top+rectangle.height==@top
        # return nil
        return Rectangle.new(
            :top=>rectangle.top,
            :left=>rectangle.left,
            :height=>rectangle.height+@height,
            :width=>rectangle.width
        )
    else
        return nil
    end
end

public def to_rects
    Rectangles.new([self])
end

public def >(rectangle)
    return true if @height>rectangle.height
    return true if @width>rectangle.width
    return false
end

public def +(rectArg)
    # @@log<<"Rectangle#+  ==================================================="
    # @@log<<"rectArg: #{rectArg.class}"
    newTop=[@top,rectArg.top].min
    newLeft=[@left,rectArg.left].min
    newHeight=[bottom,rectArg.bottom].max+1-newTop
    newWidth=[right,rectArg.right].max+1-newLeft
    Rectangle.new(
        :top=>newTop,
        :left=>newLeft,
        :height=>newHeight,
        :width=>newWidth
    )
end
```

end

Comment: Please post the code you tried and the community will review it.

Comment: So I did.......

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your own method to find out if objects are equal.

```
class Rectangle
  attr_accessor :top, :left, :width, :height

  def initialize(top, left, width, height)
    @top = top
    @left = left
    @width = width
    @height = height
  end

  def ==(rect)
    @top == rect.top &&
    @left == rect.left &&
    @width == rect.width &&
    @height == rect.height
  end
end

rect1 = Rectangle.new(10, 10, 20, 30)
rect2 = Rectangle.new(20, 20, 10, 15)
rectangles = [rect1, rect2]

rect3 = Rectangle.new(30, 30, 10, 10)
rectangles.include?(rect3) # false

rect_dup = rect1.dup
rectangles.include?(rect_dup) # true
```

Edit: Added benchmark

```
require 'benchmark'

rectangles = []

1.upto(1000) do |i|
  rectangles << Rectangle.new(i, i, 10, 10)
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(:missing_rectangles) do
    1.upto(1000) do |i|
      rect = Rectangle.new(i, i + 5, 10, 10)
      rectangles.include?(rect)
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

```
                    user       system     total    real
missing_rectangles  0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.107022)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did it already this way, and it's much too slow. With duplicates I meant overlapping areas.

New rectangles should be added very efficiently without creating overlapping areas. Greatest thing were if fitting neighbor rectangles were summarized to one rectangle with very high performance.

Comment: I need to create these rectangles for every single frame so you can imagine it should be much faster.

Comment: If you have existing rectangles displayed and you add new rectangle it will take just 0.0001s (according to benchmark) to find out if the rectangle already exists - that is pretty fast even if you do it 100 times per second (100 fps).

Comment: It's important to avoid overlapping areas. I use these rectangles to speed up the frame rate. So it would be the opposite effect if there are areas painted twice or more on the screen. The functions adding rectangles are "stupid" and don't know if parts of the added rectangles are already in the array.

Comment: I cannot help you much if we talk theoretically. Share your code with us in the "Code review" community.

Comment: Another, much faster concept would be nice.