# Calculate leading ones in binary depiction of integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary, bit

I'm searching for a fast function (without strings)

```
leading_ones(0b11101)      # =>3
leading_ones(0b1111000110) # =>4
```

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: why do you need this, what have you tried

Comment: It belongs to an approach to solve a bigger problem, see there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318312/binary-calculations-ruby

Comment: seems like a homework problem (why not use a string?) but I'm eager to see an answer regardless out of curiosity

Comment: It's no homework. Shall make a graphical user interface more performant. Strings are much too slow.

Comment: Is there a maximum (binary) length for the integers you are going to convert?

Comment: Not really. A definite maximum length can't be predicted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def leading_ones(n)
  nbr = 0
  (n.bit_length-1).downto(0) do |i|
    return nbr if n[i].zero?
    nbr += 1
  end
  nbr
end

leading_ones(6)
  #=> 2
```

Note `6.to_s(2) #=> "110"`. This uses the methods [Fixnum#bit_length](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-bit_length) and [Fixnum#[]](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't know the function bit_length and just found out that the alternative Math.log2 I used creates rounding errors to cap it all. You delivered the correct implementation of my approach.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient solution, but it works.

```
def leading_ones(num)
  counter = 0
  while num > 0
    if num % 2 == 0
      counter = 0
    else
      counter += 1
    end

    num = num / 2
  end
  counter
end

leading_ones(0b111) # => 3
leading_ones(0b11101) # => 3
leading_ones(0b111101) # => 4
leading_ones(0b1000) # => 1
leading_ones(0b01000) # => 1
```

Comment: Thank you kallax. I remember you from my first question regarding this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297163/trying-to-store-many-rectangles-without-duplicate-areas-efficiently-in-ruby

Any idea without a loop? That would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Your version with a loop is actually a bit faster, but FWIW, here's a version without a loop:

```
def leading_ones(n)
    # Number of bits needed to hold `n` as an unsigned integer
    bits = n.bit_length
    # `digits` bits, all on
    max_possible = (1 << bits) - 1
    # Flips all of `n`'s bits
    flipped = n ^ max_possible
    # First right-index of a zero in `n`, or the first index of a 1 in `flipped`
    first_zero_rindex = flipped.bit_length
    # Left-index of the first zero
    first_zero_index = bits - first_zero_rindex
    first_zero_index
end
```

Comment: Under the hood, `bit_length` is basically a loop. BTW, you can use `(1 << bits) - 1` to avoid the expensive exponentiation.

Comment: Surely there are many loops under the hood, at the latest on hardware level. But if I add additional loops on high level, it gets slower in general. Thank you both for your contribution!

Comment: @Stefan I'm surprised Ruby doesn't optimize `2**n` to `1 << n` where n is a positive integer. Still, I edited my answer to use bitshifting for `max_possible`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach so far:

```
def leading_ones(arg)
    c=0
    log=Math.log2(arg).to_i
    max_index.downto(0){|i|
        if arg[i]==1
            c+=1
        else
            return c
        end
    }
    return c
end
```

Any idea without a loop? I think it should be possible to calculate a number from another without iteration.

**added:**

Okay, it's already pretty fast and I think I'll take this solution. But another one without a loop would be perfect :-)

Ideas welcome!

**added:**

Don't use my approach. It creates rounding errors. See the selected answer for a correct version.